# use java.util.function.Function to implement Factory Design Pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns

Is it correct to use java.util.function.Function to implement Factory Design Pattern

In the following example, I've used Function reference to instantiated a Person type object.

```
import java.util.function.Function;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Function<String , Person> myFunc = (String s) -> new Person(s);
        Person p = myFunc.apply("John");
        System.out.println(p.getName());
    }
}

class Person{
    private String name;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }  
}
```

Comment: Sure, why not? Although `Function<String , Person> myFunc = Person::new;` would be neater. Also note that this isn't really extensible to multiple ctor params...

Comment: Factory is ambiguous. Simple factory and factory method are very different. Which pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The factory design pattern is used to hide implementation logic behind an object factory and its power is to use inheritance to achieve this. Say you would have more than one type of person, e.g. a SmartPerson and a DumbPerson (implementing the same Person base class). One could ask the factory to create either a smart or a dumb person without ever knowing about the implementation differences, since all it ever returns is a Person object.

You can instantiate a person with a function referring to the constructor, but this pattern is about the location of the object creation, allowing you to hide certain implementation logic.

This hiding of logic behind a factory saves you a lot of time in the future where different classes may use the factory to create persons, because a change to the way you create a person would only require you to modify the creation methods in the factory and does not affect each individual class using the factory.

```
@Test
public void testSimpleFactory() {
    PersonFactory personFactory = new PersonFactory();
    Person person = personFactory.createPerson("dumb");
    person.doMath(); // prints 1 + 1 = 3
}


public class PersonFactory {

    public Person createPerson(String characteristic) {
        switch (characteristic) {
            case "smart":
                return new SmartPerson();
            case "dumb":
                return new DumbPerson();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}

public interface Person {
    void doMath();
}

public class SmartPerson implements Person {
    @Override
    public void doMath() {
        System.out.println("1 + 1 = 2");
    }
}

public class DumbPerson implements Person {
    @Override
    public void doMath() {
        System.out.println("1 + 1 = 3");
    }
}
```

Comment: Note this is an **Abstract** Factory Pattern. You pass in a `Function<String , Person>` and the receiver uses it to create a `Person` - the caller is not aware if that `Function` returns a `SmartPerson` or `DumpPerson` (to use your example). It caller is not aware if the same instance of `Person` is returned each time. This is _exactly_ what a factory pattern is supposed to do; abstract away the creation logic from the call site.

Comment: @BoristheSpider not per se, the abstract factory pattern encapsulates multiple factories

Comment: `(String s) -> new DumbPerson(s)` and `(String s) -> new SmartPerson(s)` would give you two different "factories".

Comment: @Calculator Yeah, but where would you store them for common use? I believe that's key to this pattern.

Comment: @luc14n0 that's not the key at all. The point of a factory pattern is that the decision of _what_ to create and _how_ to create it is moved. This is exactly what using a `Function` does. You wouldn't necessarily _store_ anything anywhere. In fact, your `Factory` class is in fact terrible because the caller has to decide what sort of `Person` to create, and this is exactly what an Abstract Factory Pattern is meant to avoid!

Comment: @BoristheSpider the depicted factory represents the factory pattern (or simple factory). Not to be confused with the *abstract* factory pattern or factory method pattern.

Comment: @luc14n0 see my [first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41910420/use-java-util-function-function-to-implement-factory-design-pattern/41910520#comment71002305_41910520).